# Load QImage inside QWebView

Tags: qt, qtwebkit, qimage

I have the below code

```
QWebView webView;
QImage img = QImage::fromData((unsigned char *)data, size); // comes from some data source
webView.setHtml("<html><body><img src=\"how_to_load\"/></body></html>");
webView.show();
```

where I want to load img in the webview.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is simply saving to disk and providing the relative path in the HTML code an option? You can use [QImage::save](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qimage.html#save)() to write to disk.

EDIT: If you want to load directly from the buffer you can use QImage directly into HTML images: https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtwebkit-bridge.html#pixmaps-and-images.

Comment: but this will be relatively slow & I might be be having a lot of images, which will make it even slower, whereras if there is anyway to load it directly from the memory, it would be really good.

Comment: Then specify in your question that you want to load directly from the buffer :-)